# Can you integrate Shoes apps into Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, user-interface, sinatra, shoes

How would someone integrate a Shoes GUI with something like Sinatra? How does that work or is that not possible? Would I call for it instead of an erb file? Can shoes GUIs make get, put, post, and delete requests? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use REST requests from any application, so obviously from Shoes as well. Take a look at the [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) gem - it is a quick solution for a small clients. Or you may use [Active Resource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource), the Active Record like approach.